# Blazor - parameter Value and model Model

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following for most of my razor pages:

```
/// <summary>
/// The containing page sets this value.
/// </summary>
[Parameter]
public RateItemModel? Value { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// The EditContext for the form.
/// </summary>
private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// The model for the form.
/// </summary>
private RateCardModel RateCardModel { get; set; }

public RateEventCard()
{
    RateCardModel = new RateCardModel();
    EditContext = new EditContext(RateCardModel);
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    Logger = await ScopedLoggerFactory.GetLogger();

    RateCardModel.Assign(Value!);
    SubmitEnabled = true;
}
```

The component is to be used solely in my app so I can specify how it is used. (I.e., not a library where it can be called many different ways.) In the use it is declared as:

```
<ExDataListBox Data="@Data"
               Values="@Data"
               TData="RateItemModel"
               TValue="RateItemModel"
               TextFieldName="@nameof(EventPageEditModel.Subject)"
               SelectionMode="ListBoxSelectionMode.None">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <RateEventCard Value="@context"
                       RatingChanged="OnRatingChanged"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ExDataListBox>
```

So by definition, when it is created, Value is passed a valid data object - correct? (`Data` is populated with valid objects.)

If `Value` is never changed, then this is all good - correct?

If `Value` can be change after the page is rendered, due to user action, then I have to override OnParameterSetAsync() to assign that changed value to the model - correct?

And is it correct that in my component I should not directly set and property in `Value` as the proper way to handle that is the component calls `ValueChanged` and the parent is then to update `Value` - correct?

WHich means I do need both `Value` and `Model`. Because having just `Value` would make life easier - but would bite me in the ass sooner or later - correct?

I'm asking all this because I'm finding I need this two objects & OnParameterSetAsync() code in any component that can be changed and I want to verify that there's not an easier approach.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why does Value needs to be assigned to your `RateCardModel`?

Comment: @MarvinKlein It's assigned to initialize - basically `RateCardModel = Value`. The reason for that is I'm supposed to treat `Value` as read-only so I need an editable object for the fields on the page.

Comment: What I usually do to achieve this is create a parameter called `Model` within `OnParameterSetAsync` I create a deep copy using expression trees of the object and assign this copy to a private field called `_input`. This way the _input will be updated whenever you assign a new `Model` to the component. What this does not fetch is assigned new values to the copied object when the original object changes it's content

Comment: @MarvinKlein If you write that as an answer, happy to accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is similar to the one for your earlier question.

I'm a firm believer in using record data objects.  It prevents inadvertent mutation and makes equality checking simple.  I then use *RecordEditContexts* to provide a controlled edit environment.

Here's my guess at your `RateItem`, with a demo data provider.

```cs
public record RateItem(Guid Uid, string Item, int Rating);

// Demo Data provider
public static class RateItemProvider
{
    private static List<RateItem> _items = new()
        {
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "France",3 ),
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "UK", 1 ),
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Spain", 5 ),
            new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Portugal", 4 ),
        };

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<RateItem>> GetItemsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return _items.OrderBy(item => item.Item).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public static async Task SaveAsync(RateItem updateItem)
    {
        // Do the save
        await Task.Delay(50);
        var remove = _items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Uid == updateItem.Uid);
        if (remove is not null)
        {
            _items.Remove(remove);
            _items.Add(updateItem);
        }
    }
}
```

And the edit context:

```cs
public class RateItemEditContext
{
    public Guid Uid { get; private set; }
    public string Item { get; private set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public RateItemEditContext(string item)
    {
        this.Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Rating = 0;
        Item = item;
    }

    public RateItemEditContext(RateItem item)
    {
        this.Uid = item.Uid;
        this.Rating = item.Rating;
        this.Item = item.Item;
    }

    public RateItem AsRecord =>
        new RateItem(this.Uid, this.Item, this.Rating);
}
```

My stab at your rating card:

```cs
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">@Value.Item</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Rate Me</label>
                <input @bind="_model.Rating" type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5">
            </div>
            <div class="m-2 text-end">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RateItem Value { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<RateItem> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private RateItemEditContext _model = default!;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(Value);
        
        if ( _model is null || _model.AsRecord != this.Value)
        {
            _model = new(this.Value);
            _editContext = new(_model);
        }
            return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    // Form submit on validation.
    private async Task Submit()
    {
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_model.AsRecord);
    }
}
```

And the demo page.  I've used the dictionary as I'm guessing your two questions are related to the same objects.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var context in _items)
    {
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <RatingCard @key="context.Key"
                        Value="context.Value"
                        ValueChanged="this.UpdateRateItem" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    // use a dictionary so we can separate out the index from the object and only replace the object on an update
    private Dictionary<Guid, RateItem> _items = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var items = await RateItemProvider.GetItemsAsync();
        foreach (var item in items)
            _items.Add(item.Uid, item);

    }

    private async Task UpdateRateItem(RateItem item)
    {
        _items[item.Uid] = item;
        await RateItemProvider.SaveAsync(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why both `RateItem` and `RateItemEditContext` instead of using `RateItem` as the type for both `Value` and `_model`? Is it because `RateItem` is a record and therefore has no setters? thanks

Comment: Yes, it's all about controlling mutation.  I use a read-only data pipeline and my own version of the Flux pattern, so my edit context is a Flux action.  It's provides a much more controlled environment.